# Spring Cloud PubSub Migration Error - DefaultSubscriberFactory

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I am migrating from  `3.4.2` to `5.0.2` of `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies`

Now I am facing this error:

`constructor DefaultSubscriberFactory in class com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.DefaultSubscriberFactory cannot be applied to given types;`

Here is my current code:

```
The class configuration is annotated with:
```

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = 
GcpPubSubReactiveAutoConfiguration.class)
public class PubSubConfiguration {
...
}
```

```
    @Bean
    public GcpProjectIdProvider gcpProjectIdProvider(final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
        return new DefaultGcpProjectIdProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getProjectId() {
                return applicationProperties.getGcpProjectId();
            }
        };
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mySubscriberFactory")
    public DefaultSubscriberFactory mySubscriberFactory(
        GcpProjectIdProvider gcpProjectIdProvider,
        ApplicationProperties applicationProperties
    ) throws IOException {
        final DefaultSubscriberFactory defaultSubscriberFactory = new DefaultSubscriberFactory(gcpProjectIdProvider); >>> the error is here

        var serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(applicationProperties.getGoogleCloudStorage().getAuthentication().getBytes()));

        defaultSubscriberFactory.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(serviceAccountCredentials));
        return defaultSubscriberFactory;
    }
```

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("myPubSubTemplate")
    public PubSubTemplate mercareonPubSubTemplate(
        GcpProjectIdProvider gcpProjectIdProvider,
        @Qualifier("mySubscriberFactory") SubscriberFactory subscriberFactory
    ) {
        return new PubSubTemplate(new DefaultPublisherFactory(gcpProjectIdProvider), subscriberFactory);
    }
```

It is suggesting

> DefaultSubscriberFactory(GcpProjectIdProvider)
> Use DefaultSubscriberFactory(GcpProjectIdProvider, PubSubConfiguration) instead

How to pass PubSubConfiguration ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by this way (example of code):

```
@Configuration
public class SubscriberConfig {

  @Value("${spring.cloud.gcp.project-id}")
  public String projectId;


  @Value("${gcp.subscription}")
  public String subscription;


 @Value("${spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.flow-control.max-outstanding-element-count}")
 public long maxOutstandingElement;

 
 public PubSubConfiguration configuration() {
     PubSubConfiguration conf = new PubSubConfiguration();
     conf.initialize(projectId);
     return conf;
 }


 @Bean
 public PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate(PubSubConfiguration configuration) {
   DefaultSubscriberFactory factory = new DefaultSubscriberFactory(() -> projectId, configuration);
  factory.setFlowControlSettings(
    FlowControlSettings.
        newBuilder()
        .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(maxOutstandingElement)
        .build());
factory.setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(10L));
return new PubSubSubscriberTemplate(factory);
}
```

}